# Using ssh_alias with ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I am using ssh tunneling to login to system behind gateway. 
Problem is that I have ssh_alias defined in ~/.ssh/config on gateway server. 
Where I have key and ip setup. 
But those alias don't work with nc command. 
Is there a way to use alias with nc command and use keys setting done on gateway server? So I don't need to download key on local server. 
Example:
GatewayServer

```
~/.ssh/config
Host test
HostName 192.168.1.10
IdentityFile ~/keys/test
User test
```

LocalServer
~/.ssh/config

```
  Host test
  ProxyCommand ssh gateway nc %h %p
```

Following configuration fails as nc don't know about test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you asking is almost the same as [this](https://superuser.com/a/525750/170017).

If you don't want to copy key from gateway to local box, the work around is use Method 1 (bash alias) in that post(and below). ssh_config cannot do what you want. I have detail explanation there about the difference between alias and tunnel method, which include ssh_config `ProxyCommand`.

### Method 1

In `~/.bashrc`, add following line

```
alias ssh-test='ssh -t gateway ssh test@test'
```

In command prompt, just type following

```
ssh-test
```

What `ssh -t gateway ssh test@test` do is almost the same as follow

```
local# ssh gateway
gateway# ssh test@test
```

Other than combining the two step in one, it skip opening a shell(csh, bash, etc) on `gateway`, instead starting a ssh session to `test` right after authentication.

You don't need ~/.ssh/config on local box BUT keep the one gateway for the `test` (for key usage).

Adding `ForwardAgent yes` to gatway `.ssh/config`

```
Host test
    HostName 192.168.1.10
    ForwardAgent yes
    IdentityFile ~/keys/test
    User test
```

### Method 2

If you don't want to copy gateway key to local box, but permitted to install your `local` ssh key into `test@test`. Then you can use following

local `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host gateway
    User <gateway user>
    HostName <gateway/IP>

Host test
    User test
    Hostname 192.168.1.10
    Port 22
    ProxyCommand ssh gateway nc %h %p
```

Comment: One more problem. With method one ssh-agent don't work. Every time I need to give password. Is there a solution for that

Comment: I am not 100%, but try this `alias ssh-test='ssh -t -A gateway ssh -A test@test'`. If it works I will update the answer too.

Comment: No that does not work. I have already tried that solution.

Comment: See if adding `ForwardAgent yes` to gateway config works. I updated the answer too.

Comment: that think -A option will do right?

Comment: I am not sure if it make a difference as you have config in gateway for 192.168.1.10.

Comment: Your agent communication is between `gateway` and `192.168.1.10`, right?

Comment: Yes. I have ssh-agent running on gateway to avoid giving password on every login. Which stores pass phrase of 192.168.1.10

Comment: Then in theory putting `ForwardAgent yes` into gateway config should work.

Comment: @VivekGoel I think I know the issue regarding ssh-agent. With the alias method in the answer, `gateway` is connecting to `test` without running `ssh-agent`, so `-A` or `ForwardAgent` don't matter at all, it is just not available. Try the following `ssh -t gateway ssh-agent ssh test@test`.

Comment: didn't worked :(

Comment: Do you have `ForwardAgent yes` in gateway .ssh/config? If no, try `ssh -t gateway ssh-agent ssh -A test@test`.